# Priority Queue of type integer array

Tags: java, arrays, integer, priority-queue

`PriorityQueue<int[]> maxheap = new PriorityQueue<>(Collections.reverseOrder());`

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class [I cannot be cast to class java.lang.Comparable ([I and java.lang.Comparable are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')

**I need to implement maxheap of integer array where the 0th element of array should be used as reference , where array is of length 2**

Answer (score 4):

You simply have to write your own [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html), which you give to the [PriorityQueue`s constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#PriorityQueue-java.util.Comparator-):

```
PriorityQueue<int[]> maxheap = new PriorityQueue<>((a, b) -> Integer.compare(b[0], a[0]));
```

The `Comparator` gives the `PriorityQueue` a function to compare two elements of your queue (`a` and `b` in our code). We can use the [`Integer.compare()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compare-int-int-) method to savely compare two integer values. This method simply returns an integer, which indicates if `a` is larger, `b` is larger or they are the same.

As `a` and `b` are arrays and we want to use the first element of the arrays for comparison. Therefore, we use `a[0]` and `b[0]`.

In order to get a max heap you have to compare `b` to `a`(as shown in the code above) resulting in reverse ordering. For a min heap you would have `Integer.compare(a[0], b[0])`.

**Edit:** Adapted question to incorporate a better way to compare the arrays from the first comment.